# VBA - Move attachment to inbox subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to create the following rule in Outlook:

whenever comes an email from (1) specific address and (2) with specific subject I want to run a script that moves the email's attachment into the inbox subfolder (let's call it MyFolder).

So just to make it clear: I do not want to save the attachment to hard drive folder.

I can do steps 1 and 2, but I have problems with the code for step 3. Most related questions are dealing with saving attachments to hard drive folders.

I would really appreciate your help!

Dmitri

Comment: If you can do steps 1 and 2, what is your step 3 question?

Comment: Many will be learning now that files can be manually dragged from a Windows folder into an Outlook folder. I believe there is nothing in Outlook VBA to save attachments directly to an Outlook folder.

Comment: For the sceptics - Storing files directly in Outlook folders https://www.msoutlook.info/question/575

Comment: well, thanks everyone for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> I found this example at
>   https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3747-outlook-auto-download-save-attachments-to-folder.html

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sSaveFolder As String

  sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\DT168\Documents\outlook-attachments\"
  For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
  Next

End Sub
```

Also you can add a Rule (step by step example is shown in the page).

Comment: The OP has already found how to do this. "I do not want to save the attachment to hard drive folder."

Answer (score 0):

An Outlook folder can't contain files. You need to created a document item if it is an Office document (like Word or Excel). Or you will have to create an Outlook item and add the attached file to it.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: Storing files directly in Outlook folders https://www.msoutlook.info/question/575

Comment: If you take a look a bit closer, you can see a document item (the message class starts with IPM.Document) with a corresponding file attached.

Comment: I have dragged a Word document directly into an Outlook folder.

Comment: Yes, you can drag a file. But the file is stored in the Outlook folder as an attachment to the document item.